# Helm: Value.yaml set Static ip on GCE

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How do you use an existing static IP address when installing a Helm Chart?

I have installed `helm install stable/nginx-ingress`

I have followed [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/ingress-with-static-ip) and added the following to value.yaml:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true",
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce",
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "kubernetes-ingress"
  }
```

Thinking it will find the named static ip: "kubernetes-ingress"

from this:

```
gcloud compute addresses create kubernetes-ingress --global
```